# VB.NET Extract ZIP File with Progressbar

Tags: vb.net

I need to Extract the ZIP File without lag and with Progressbar, so i made this code.

```
    Private Async Sub Downloader_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles Downloader.DownloadFileCompleted
    Dim worker As New Task(Sub()
                               Dim username As String
                               username = Environment.UserName
                               ZipToUnpack = "C:\Users\" & username & "\Documents\InfinityHexLauncher\Instances\InfinityHex.zip"
                               Ziel = "C:\Users\" & username & "\Documents\InfinityHexLauncher\Instances"

                               Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read("C:\Users\" & username & "\Documents\InfinityHexLauncher\Instances\InfinityHex.zip")
                                   Dim Entry As ZipEntry
                                   For Each Entry In zip
                                       AddHandler zip.ExtractProgress, AddressOf MEP
                                       Entry.Extract(Ziel, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
                                   Next
                               End Using
                           End Sub)
    worker.Start()
    Await worker
End Sub
```

I dont have any lag now but no Progressbar and also no idea for it...

```
    Private Sub MEP(sender As Object, e As ExtractProgressEventArgs)
        byteszip.Text = e.BytesTransferred
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is Sub MEP? This is where you would update you progress bar. You should also set the value to =0 and set a maximum for it. I don't see any of that in your code.

Comment: `Private Sub MEP(sender As Object, e As ExtractProgressEventArgs)
        byteszip.Text = e.BytesTransferred
    End Sub`

Here it is, i want to have everything in a label now. But i got an Error: "Invalid Cross-Threading Process"

Comment: Add this to your question

Comment: There's no trace of a progress bar

Comment: So, yea is there a way to get a label with percent indication of this whole Extractionprogress?

Comment: Yes but you haven't program as progress bar. Or if you have one it doesn't show in your code